# Animated css change (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, animation, easing, easing-functions

I was trying apply jQuery easing plugin to .css and .animate, but not working, i dont know why, because normally it works.
Code example:

```
$('#img').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({"border-radius":"5px"}, 0, "easeOutBounce");
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({"border-radius":"75px"}, 0, "easeOutBounce");
});
```

So basically .animate (instead of .css to avoid problems) but i want also set animation duration and working `"easeOutBounce"` or some of other effects.

Now border radius is animated on `:hover`, but without animation timing.

I cannot do it in css, and jQuery is not working, is there some way to fix this?

Thanks,
Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the syntax you are using in your animation is not correct. Also, you need to set a duration > 0 if you want to see something.

Feel free to change the `easing` part with your own plugin.

```js
$('#img').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).animate({
      borderRadius: 75
    }, 300, 'easeOutBounce');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).animate({
      borderRadius: 5
    }, 300, 'easeOutBounce');
  }
);
```

```css
#img {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<img id="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk0jX.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not working with effect.. for example i want easeOutBounce, (http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) and it not works :/ .

Comment: Is possible make this timing effect.. in jquery? If plugin not works with .animate (idk why)

Comment: Hi @Oliver, I changed the easing to `easeOutBounce`, you can check in my snippet.

Answer (score 1):

This function should work:

```js
$('#img').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).animate({
      borderRadius: 75
    }, 300, 'easeOutBounce');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).animate({
      borderRadius: 5
    }, 300, 'easeOutBounce');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to modify timing effects like
`ease out bounce`

change it to `ease in`